# How to combine data into a temporary table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, temp-tables

I have a very large table called `paypal_ipn_orders`. In this table I have 2 important bits of information a row called `item_name` and a row called `sort_num`. I want to use certain parameters to pull out records from `paypal_ipn_orders` and put them into a temporary table called `temp_table`. I know how to select the records as follows

```
SELECT `item_name`, `sort_num` 
FROM `paypal_ipn_orders`
WHERE `packing_slip_printed` = 0
AND LOWER(`payment_status`) = `completed`
AND `address_name` <> ''
```

That query selects all the records I want to move to the temporary database I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use MySQL's [Insert Into Select](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/mysql-insert-select-example/) I added generic data types to the columns in the temp table, you'll want to find out what the actual data types are from your table and make them the same.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (
    item_name varchar(50), 
    sort_num int
);

INSERT INTO temp_table (item_name, sort_num)
SELECT `item_name`, `sort_num` 
FROM `paypal_ipn_orders`
WHERE `packing_slip_printed` = 0
AND LOWER(`payment_status`) = `completed`
AND `address_name` <> ''
```

Comment: does that create the temporary table automatically?

Comment: No you will want to create the temporary table first and then reference it by name in your `INSERT` statement. Are familiar with how to create a temp table in MySQL?

Comment: Yes. If this answer helped you achieve your goal, please accept it. If not please provide information on any issues you have run into with it.

Comment: Well this give me a mysql error, here is how I'm doing it. 
    `mysql_query ("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (
    item_name TEXT, 
    sort_num int
    )
    INSERT INTO temp_table (item_name, sort_num)
    SELECT `item_name`, `sort_num` 
    FROM `paypal_ipn_orders`
    WHERE `packing_slip_printed` = 0
    AND LOWER(`payment_status`) = `completed`
    AND `address_name` <> ''"
    );

It gives me a syntax error at line 5

Comment: Even when I try and do this through php my admin it doesn't work. Creating the temporary table and columns works but `INSERT INTO` doesn't work. I have run into this problem before what I was told was I need to use `UPDATE temp_table SET sort_num =` and so forth I just am not sure how to go about it.