# Insert data from a table to a temporary table, and then select from the temp table specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql, temp-tables

I'm trying to get rows from an existing table (by columns: `p_id`, `e_id`, `ts`, `data1`, `data2`, `data3`) to a temporary table (indexed by `p_id`, `e_id`, `ts`), and then selecting specific rows from that temporary table as a result. Then terminate the temporary table (because that's what CREATE TEMPORARY does, right?)

I reviewed these 2 posts:

- [How to combine data into a temporary table in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993837/how-to-combine-data-into-a-temporary-table-in-mysql)
- [Create a temporary table in a SELECT statement without a separate CREATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table)

and got all confused with getting the query written properly (my query doesn't run).

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
  pet_temp ( INDEX(p_id, e_id, ts) )  
AS (
  SELECT p_id, e_id, ts, data1, data2, data3
  FROM processes_history
  WHERE e_id=4362 AND ts BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-04-01'
) SELECT p_id, e_id, ts, data1, data2, data3 FROM pet_temp WHERE p_id IN (11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
  pet_temp ( INDEX(p_id, e_id, ts) )  
AS (
  SELECT p_id, e_id, ts, data1, data2, data3
  FROM processes_history
  WHERE e_id=4362 AND ts BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-04-01'
) ;
SELECT p_id, e_id, ts, data1, data2, data3 FROM pet_temp WHERE p_id IN (11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99);

Drop temporary table if exists pet_temp ;
```

Comment: This works! Is there a way to name the columns in "pet_temp"? Fetching the data as an associative array results NULLs. `while ( $row = db_fetch_assoc($query) ) { $new[$row['p_id']] = $row['e_id'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
  pet_temp ( INDEX(p_id, e_id, ts) )  
AS 
  SELECT p_id, e_id, ts, data1, data2, data3
  FROM processes_history
  WHERE e_id=4362 AND ts BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-04-01';

 SELECT p_id, e_id, ts, data1, data2, data3 FROM pet_temp WHERE p_id IN (11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99);
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS pet_temp;
```

Looks like you just need to remove the first set of (), and add a semicolon between the statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query, it will give desire in table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pet_temp (INDEX(p_id, e_id, ts))
SELECT p_id, e_id, ts, data1, data2, data3
FROM (
    SELECT p_id, e_id, ts, data1, data2, data3 
    FROM processes_history   
    WHERE e_id=4362 AND ts BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-04-01'
) x
WHERE p_id IN (11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99);
SELECT * FROM pet_temp;
```

Don't need to drop pet_temp table, it will get dropped automatically one session is closed.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need the temporary table for if you're not planing on using it later?

The next won't do the job?

```
SELECT p_id, e_id, ts, data1, data2, data3 FROM processes_history WHERE e_id=4362 AND p_id IN (11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99) AND ts BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-04-01';
```

Please correct me if i'm missing something